# How to change the liferay database to mysql database

Tags: liferay-6

I have downloaded the liferay6 bundle with tomcat.I need to change the liferay database to mysql database.I have searched in google and as per information i have created the portal-ext.properties with below lines of code.

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=root123
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool
schema.run.enabled=true
schema.run.minimal=true
```

and i modified the ROOT.xml.Now the code in that file is :

```
<Context path="" crossContext="true">

<Resource
    name="jdbc/LiferayPool"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    username="root"
    password="root123"
    maxActive="20"
/> 
</Context>
```

and i have created the lportal database in mysql.Do i need to modify anything more.If i do like this i am not even able to see the default login page of liferay.Can anyone point me where i am doing wrong.Thank You.

I am getting the below Exception if i am doing like this.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:148)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)




org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAutoProxyCreator#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'serviceAdvice' while setting bean property 'methodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'asyncAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'asyncAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'threadLocalCacheAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadLocalCacheAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'bufferedIncrementAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bufferedIncrementAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'indexableAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexableAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liferayTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'platformTransactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1-updating java connector driver**

be sure that the liferay portal is not started ! if it does, then shut down.

download and install MySQL and HeidiSQL, you can simply create mysql database via HeidiSql.

download mysql.jar (Connector/J) from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)
you may not login just go below in page and click link: **No thanks, just start my download.**

delete  **mysql.jar** in **liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\lib\ext**

copy mysql-connector-java-*some version*-bin.jar  in 
**\Program Files(x86)\MySQL\Connector J** folder and

paste it in liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\lib\ext .(don't forget to rename it to mysql.jar)

**2- work with control panel of liferay**
now  you can start liferay portal

open in browser localhost:8080/
go to -> control panel -> server administration -> Data Migration

**JDBC Driver Class Name:**
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

**JDBC URL:**
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/***DB-NAME***?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false

***DB-NAME*** - name of database you've created earlier.

write MySQL username and password then click the button below.

now in the next page you can see some text in the ***red border***like : ***The system is currently undergoing maintenance. Please try again later.***

**It's allright.** just wait for .. may be half an hour or more or less, **just wait**, and be patient))

while process is going, you can do the next last step:

**3- change portal properties**
open file **portal-ext.properties** (create it if doesn't exist) in **liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes**  and paste to this file following text:

jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:**here must be DB port, by default it's *3306***/***DB_NAME***?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false

jdbc.default.username=***username of MySQL user***

jdbc.default.password=***password of MySQL user***

***THAT'S IT***

RESTART TOMCAT SERVER

Answer (score 0):

In your `portal-ext.properties` file, it should be enough if you specif JNDI name to lookup.

`jdbc.default.jndi.name=MyDataSource`

In your Tomcat's xml file,

```
<Resource
    name="MyDataSource"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    username="root"
    password="root123"
    maxActive="20"
/>
```

Make sure that the user you are using above (root) has privilege to create the tables.

Also, don't forget to restart your Tomcat container.

Even on top of this if it doesn't work, share the exceptions in your (bin) logs.

Comment: Hi Vikas Thanks for giving the reply.The exception i am getting is posted in my original question.